# Adding Names to Scatter Plot Points Without Modifying X-Values (Excel 2007 VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, charts, scatter

I am attempting to modify the tooltips of a scatter plot using Visual Basic code so that the name of the data points are in the tooltips when you click on individual data points, along with the x and y data from the plot.

I have already attempted to use:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plot").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SetSourceData Source:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col1 & ", " & col2), PlotBy:=xlColumns
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plot").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(col3)
```

But when I try to use it, the macro overwrites the X-value data already stored in the data points in order to add the names to the scatter plot tooltips. Is there any way that I can modify the names of the scatter plot points without modifying their x-values or using Add-Ins?

Answer (score 1):

The following code sets the Data Label (Data Callout) to the values provided in the Range "Sheet1!$K$10:$K$20". Change this reference to the cells where you have the content you would like to display and you should be good to go.

Best regards
Christian

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plot").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.  InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, "=Sheet1!$K$10:$K$20", 0
```

Then add the following to also display them properly:

```
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plot").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).
     .ShowRange = True
     .ShowCategoryName = False
     .ShowValue = False
End With
```

Comment: Okay, so I've tried changing the reference to the cells where I have content to display, but now I am getting an error that says "Run-time error -2147467259(80004005) Unable to get the Count property of the DataLabels class". Do you know what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Hm, if you provided more code, or a life example this would be easier. One possible solution could be to add: 
`Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to (enter number of values in scatter plot)'
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plot").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).HasDataLabel = _
         True
Next i`
in front of the `dataLables.format.text....` line, so you specifically tell excel to create data labels for the chart.